# Suggestion; Manga/Anime genre page?

Tags: discussion

It may have already been suggested or may exists if so I apologise, but if not I was thinking it might be a nice idea to have a section give a basic description of the different genres of manga/anime. Because some are more well know than others and it'd save people having to ask?

Comment: there's wikipedia which does this well enough imo

Comment: also: https://www.google.com/search?q=anime+genres

Comment: Yeah I know and you can always google it, just thought I'd bring it up and see what people thought.